# Unable to execute command using UsbSerialPort in android

Tags: java, android

i have done initial steps like connecting to device ,searching and open,using git hub library .

https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

but i am unable to send command to cisco router using console port .
i done following changes on my SerialConsoleActivity in onResume method.

```
  sPort.setRTS(true);
//sPort.setDTR(true);   
  String command="show ?";
  byte[] commandByteArray = command.getBytes();
  sPort.write(commandByteArray, 5000);
```

i want to execute command , read output on my android handset.

this is my first post if you need any description about class please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing using sPort.write, library already provide

```
SerialInputOutputManager
```

Use **`method onCreate()`** using button and text.
I am sharing following code for write to cisco console port:

```
     commandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
       {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String command = commandEnter.getText().toString().trim();
            command = command + "\r\n";
            consoleText.append("Command > " + command);
            mSerialIoManager.writeAsync(command.getBytes());
        }
    });
```

Now whenever a data received it will call method updateReceivedData(byte[] data)
Inside method :

```
consoleText.append(new String(data));        


mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, consoleText.getBottom());
```

Now am able to get command output and initial router configuration....

Happy Coding :)